# VS2008 automaticly add usings disable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a compoment developed by myself.
E.g.: Logger.Charts.Exchart() is the constructor.

Now I use "using" in my Form:

```
Using Logger.Charts;
Exchart x = Exchart();
```

But every time I click on my component on the designer, it automaticly edit the constructor to:

```
Exchart x = Logger.Charts.Exchart();
```

How can I disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is in the .designer file, you can't stop this behavior.

During code gen the WinForms designer will spit fully qualified names of all types.  There is no way to disable this behavior.

I *believe* this is done in order to avoid namespace collision issues.